# Can a variable be initialised by extracting from std::cin?

Tags: c++, io, initialization

Is it possible to implement something similar to this?

```
cin >> int num;
```

The reason for doing this is because I am trying to read standard inputstream for a loop sentinel value. The current code is:

```
int num;
for (cin >> num; num > 0; --num) {...}
```

If I can implement what I am asking for, num can be removed from the external scope which never uses it, limiting it to just within the for-loop, thus saving memory.

Comment: @user657267 you'll calling cin every iteration. I need to call it only once before the loop starts.

Comment: @M.M and where would I put the cin statement? I only need to call cin to initialize num once, so I can't exactly put it inside the loop.

Comment: @M.M wouldn't that be called every iteration?

Comment: @M.M do you mean for ( {int num; cin >> num;}; num > 0; --num) ? If that's what you mean, isn't num then local in scope to only within the bracers, and will be out of scope once we exit into the loop body?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some options:

---

```
{
    int num = 0;
    for (cin >> num; num > 0; --num) {...}
}
```

---

```
for (int num = 0, unused = !(cin >> num); num > 0; --num) { ... }
```

---

*Credit to TonyD for this one:*

```
for (int num = (cin >> num ? num : 0); num > 0; --num) { ... }
```

---

```
int read_int() { int x = 0; cin >> x; return x; }

// ...

for (int num = read_int(); num > 0; --num) { ... }
```

---

```
for (int num = [](){ int x = 0; cin >> x; return x; }(); num > 0; --num) { ... }
```

---

NB. These versions skip the loop in case of read failure. You may wish to throw an exception instead, or something.

Comment: On [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6024530731aec8ff), the `unused = cin >> num` version gives `error: invalid user-defined conversion from 'std::basic_istream<char>::__istream_type {aka std::basic_istream<char>}' to 'int'`, as the candidate conversion was `::operator void*() const` and there's `no known conversion from 'void*' to 'int'`.  Seems GCC's Standard Library has moved to `iostream::operator bool() const` yet, which would hopefully fix this.

Comment: @TonyD fixed. I admit I didn't try it. The problem is that the `operator bool` is `explicit`.

Comment: FWIW, `int num = (cin >> num, num);` seems to work too, though even if `operator,` being a sequence point makes it legit (and I'm not 100% sure), it'll concern enough reviewers of the code and waste their time it's not worth actually using.

Comment: @TonyD pro. Have added a slight variation if you don't mind

Comment: Nice variation - solid for C++03 too.  Cheers.

Comment: @TonyD Cute solution.

Answer (score 1):

I mean if this is just about inline initialization then you can use an [`istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) to accomplish this.

```
for(int i = *istream_iterator<int>(cin); i > 0; --i)
```

[[Live Example](http://ideone.com/mdHiqs)]

This will fail just as spectacularly as `cin >> i` would if you were reading in something other than an `int` from the standard input. Just bear in mind, you're sacrificing error checking for a one line initialization. A better approach would probably be to write a repeating prompt of sorts:

```
int readInt(){
    int result;

    cout << "Please input a number: ";

        while(!(cin >> result)){
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "Error\nPlease input a number: ";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then just calling:

```
for(int i = readInt(); i > 0; --i)
```

Comment: `cin >> i` is well-defined in case of extraction failure.

Comment: @M.M. that's true since C++11 (`i` is guaranteed to be 0 after failure)

Comment: @M.M I know that this is defined, I just don't think translating an invalid input as a 0 would be desired behavior.

Comment: @JonathanMee It would mean the loop does not get entered, which seems as good an option as any, outside of adding another code path

Comment: @M.M I personally think that the only time the loop should execute 0 times is if the user enters 0.

Comment: FWIW, an alternative is to use exceptions for I/O error handling: call `cin.exceptions(std::ios::eofbit | std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit);` before using `*istream_iterator<int>(cin)`.

Comment: @TonyD It's sad that the question hasn't demanded more, If you feel like typing that up anyway though, let me know and you'll certainly get a +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

`cin >> num` is simply syntactical sugar for `cin.operator>>(num)` which might as well be `cin.foo(num)`. So let's just call it `foo(num)`. No you're basically saying you want to use:

```
void foo(int& arg) {
    cin >> arg;
}
// ...
foo(int i);
```

To define `i` as an `int` and initialize it to some user input. Not C++ as it currently stands.  Nor ever I might suppose.